# Exclude value out of Rand gen_range

Tags: random, rust, rust-cargo

I would like to have a random number between `-max` and `max` where max is some `i32` value, but I would like to exclude zero. I am using `rand` version `0.8.5`.

I would like to have a code something like

```
let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
rng.gen_range(-max..max);
```

But this code has zero included. Is there an idiomatic way to exclude it?

Comment: You can `gen_range(-max+1..max);` and if the value is 0 change it to `-max`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, actually this is the way that I already implemented it. But from my point of view, this is non-idiomatic. I think I'll create my own crate that works over discrete regions.